# Select Join Where and orWhere in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, select, join

I have two tables- jobseekers and resumes. I try to achieve three search options- by entering 1. "first name", 2. "last name", and 3. "first name + last name". My current code is as below:

```
    $q = \Request::get('keyword');
    $data['resume'] = Resume::join('jobseekers', 'jobseekers.user_id', '=', 'resumes.user_id')
        ->where('jobseekers.first_name','like','%'.$q.'%')
        ->orWhere('jobseekers.last_name','like','%'.$q.'%')
        ->orderBy('resumes.updated_at','desc')->paginate(50);
```

Using my texbox (keywords), When I search only last / first name, it works fine. However, when I type both first + last name in the textbox, it shows no result.

Please share me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CONCAT()`:

```
 ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(jobseekers.first_name, ' ', jobseekers.last_name)"), 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
```

Comment: I use this:
        $data['resume'] = Resume::join('jobseekers', 'jobseekers.user_id', '=', 'resumes.user_id')->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('jobseekers.first_name', ' ', 'jobseekers.first_name')"), 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');

But I got error: Undefined variable: q

Comment: field name shouldn't be enclosed with ' ', i guess. it is exact similar of `WHERE CONCAT( field1, ' ' , filed2 ) like '% $q%' `

Comment: ->Where(CONCAT(jobseekers.first_name, ' ', jobseekers.last_name), 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%'); I got error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\CONCAT()

Comment: `$q = \Request::get('keyword');
$data['resume'] = Resume::join('jobseekers', 'jobseekers.user_id', '=', 'resumes.user_id')
        ->where('jobseekers.first_name','like','%'.$q.'%')
        ->orWhere('jobseekers.last_name','like','%'.$q.'%')
        ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(jobseekers.first_name, ' ', jobseekers.last_name)"), 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
        ->orderBy('resumes.updated_at','desc')->paginate(50);`
 should work

Comment: @Naren i mean the above query is exact similar to standard SQL query `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT( field1, ' ' , filed2 ) like '% $ %'`

Comment: This works great. Anyway, I still have concern about SQL injection problem when using DB::raw...

Answer (score 0):

Use where and or where like this

```
  $results = App\Table::select('*')
   ->where(function ($query) use ($search_term) {
        $query->where('column3', 'like', $search_term.'%')
              ->orWhere('column4', 'like', $search_term.'%')
   })
   ->orderBy('column1', 'asc')
   ->get();
```

Hope this help

Comment: It works only we enter first name or last name, but when entering first name with last name, it displays nothing.